# Terminate EC2 instances, based on tags, using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I`m struggling to get this working without success.. Here my playbook.

First a search my machines by tag and later try to terminate them.

```
   - name: EC2 Facts
     ec2_instance_facts:
      region: us-east-1
      filters:
        "tag:Type": "staging"
      aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
     register: ec2

   - name: Kill EC2 Instance
     ec2:
     instance_ids: "{{ item.instance_id }}"
     state: "{{ state }}"
     region: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_REGION') }}"
     aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
     aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
     with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

running like this:

```
ansible-playbook ec2_id_kill.yml --extra-vars "state=absent"
```

Looks ansible cannot find the **instance_id** from the facts

Comment: What is the error message? Can you fix the code indentation?

Comment: "msg": "image parameter is required for new instance" looks ansible cannot get the correct **instance_id**. I`m using ansible-2.4

Comment: It is likely the passed `state` value is not used/honored. It is using the default value of `present` and trying to create an instance. Cannot help if you don't fix the indentation.

Comment: even change state=stoppped still not working looks like cannot find **instance_id**

Answer (score 2):

I am using this to terminate the single instance, you can adjust this to terminate multiple instance:

```
- name: EC2 Facts
  ec2_instance_info:
    region: us-east-1
    filters:
      "tag:Type": "staging"
    aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
  register: ec2

- name: Kill EC2 Instance
  ec2:
    instance_ids: "{{ ec2.instances[0].id }}"
    state: "{{ state }}"
    region: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_REGION') }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
```

Hope that help you

Comment: Still not working... error: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "image parameter is required for new instance"}

Comment: from the message it shows that you are trying to create new instance instead of terminating the old one. please share your complete playbook

Comment: For me in needed to be  instance_ids: "{{ ec2.instances[0].instance_id }}"